# Compiling patterns as Lists

Tags: python, regex

So I am currently transferring some code from R to Python. The file, I am loading to deal with grep is in the format as follows:

```
match                                               id
(chief\s+marketing\s+officer)|(\bc\.?m\.?o\.?\b)    3
(chief\s+technology\s+officer)|(\bc\.?t\.?o\.?\b)   4
(chief\s+information\s+officer)|(\bc\.?i\.?o\.?\b)  5
(\bdirector\b)                                      11
```

I'm having issues as I load this into a pandas dataframe, and precompile the patterns.

```
def compilePatterns():
    matches = levels['match']
    patterns = []
    for match in matches:
        pat = re.compile(r''+ match)
        patterns.append(pat)
    return patterns
```

So now, using my extraction function:

```
def extract(title):
    title = title.lower()
    print title
    for index,pattern, in enumerate(patterns):
        match = pattern.match(title)
        if match:
            return levels.iloc[index]['id']
    return None
```

It works well if I do extract('director') which I get 10, but if I do: extract('Pet director') it returns None. Hence director is never being picked up.

I'm not sure whether the issue is when I am compiling the patterns, as they have brackets everywhere or if this is a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pattern.match` will only return matches that are at the *beginning* of a string. Since `\bdirector\b` does not appear at the beginning of the string `'Pet director'`, `pattern.match('Pet director')` will not return anything.

What you want is `pattern.search` (or `re.search(pattern, ...)`), which will return matches that are found *anywhere* in the string.

Comment: thanks very much! Yes I realise now, a match is at the start.  Seems the search has cleared up my issues. Thanks again